# Extra class dictionary to manage multiple action

Tags: c#

A `QueueTask` class is for running an action with queue. I want to create multiple queues and handle the queue which is the lower task and then add a queue there.

Also it should be able to auto create new queues, cancel and remove.

However, queue method efficiency seems a bit low, what could be improved?

```
public class QueueTaskExtra
{
    private static int m_Counter = 0;
    private Dictionary<int, QueueTask> QueuePool = new Dictionary<int, QueueTask>();
    public int QueuePoolID { get; private set; } = 0;

    public QueueTaskExtra()
    {
        this.QueuePoolID = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref m_Counter);
        QueuePool.Add(QueuePoolID, new QueueTask());
    }

    public void NewQueue()
    {
        this.QueuePoolID = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref m_Counter);
        QueuePool.Add(QueuePoolID, new QueueTask());
    }

    public void Queue(ActionInfo ai)
    {
        QueueTask qt = new QueueTask();
        int tmpCount = 999999999;
        foreach (var qf in QueuePool)
        {
            if(qf.Value.Count() < tmpCount)
            {
                qt = qf.Value;
                tmpCount = qf.Value.Count();
            }
        }
        qt.Queue(ai);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `ConcurrentQueue`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes, the class 'QueueTask' is using ConcurrentQueue

Comment: I want to create multiple ConcurrentQueue  and create a handler , same as threadpool